# Parse a character outside a tag in xml

Tags: python, regex, xml

I have a file like the following

```
<xml>
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">some</LM>
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">word</LM>:
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">some</LM>
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">other</LM>,
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">word</LM>
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">and</LM>.
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">so</LM>
<LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">on</LM>.
</xml>
```

Now, I can correctly parse the document using minidom in python, but I also want to get the punctuation marks outside the tags and put them inside with a specific tag for each mark. Like this:

```
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">some</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">word</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="colon">:</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">some</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">other</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="comma">,</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">word</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">and</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="eos">.</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">so</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="bla">on</LM>
    <LM lm="blablabla" catg="eos">.</LM>
```

I feel I should not use regex to do this, but how then? Is there a safe way to do it?

This is what I did so far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import codecs
import io
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import unicodedata
import re

pos_conversion_rules = {
    'a$':'A',
    'blablabla':'BLABLABLA'
}

def look_up(i):
    for k in pos_conversion_rules:
        pattern = re.compile(k)
        if pattern.match(i):            
            return pos_conversion_rules[k]


#non apro il file direttamente con minidom perché non riesce a riconvertire i caratteri speciali xml
datasource = codecs.open("/CORPUS.xml", "r")
datasource = datasource.read()

#non converto subito in utf8
datasource = unescape(datasource,
                      {
                          "&agrave;":"x01",
                          "&egrave":"x02",
                          "&igrave":"x03",
                          "&ograve":"x04",
                          "&ugrave":"x05",
                          "&eacute":"y01",
                          "&oacute":"y02",
                          "&apos;": "z01",
                          "&quot;": 'z02'
                      })

#parsing 
document = parseString(datasource)

node = document.getElementsByTagName('LM')

#inizializzo i vettori di lunghezza pari a quella della lista dei nodi
token = [0]*len(node)
pos = [0]*len(node)
lemma = [0]*len(node)

#estraggo i dati e converto le pos attraverso la funzione look_up definita sopra
for i in  range(len(node)):
    token[i] = node[i].firstChild.data
    for attrName, attrValue in node[i].attributes.items():
        #controllo di non avere problemi con i lemmi
        if attrName == "lemma":
            if len(attrValue)>0:
                lemma[i] = attrValue
            else:
                lemma[i] = ("NaN")
        elif attrName == "catg":
            x = [look_up(attrValue),attrValue]
            pos[i] = x


#creo il dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'pos':pos,
    'token':token,
    'lemma': lemma
},columns=('token','pos','lemma'))

print df.to_string
```

Comment: Can you show what you code?

Comment: Have you looked at [the .tail attribute](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#what-about-that-trailing-text-on-serialised-elements) of the elements?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use lxml but the fact is that I can't handle escaped characters. I get the following error `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'agrave' not defined, line 18, column 33
`

Comment: you can set `recover=True` for the `lxml`'s parser to ignore undefined entities, or using `lxml.html` module

Comment: Thank you, this two things (the .tail attribute and recover=True) were exactly what I wanted for my purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
from lxml import etree
import sys
import os
import glob
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import re


pos_conversion_rules = {
    '[.;:?!]':'XPS',
    '[,]':'XPW',
    'blablabla':'BLABLA'
}

def look_up(i):
    for k in pos_conversion_rules:
        pattern = re.compile(k)
        if pattern.match(i):            
            return pos_conversion_rules[k]

path = "~/where/my/files/are/"
f = "*.xml"
docs = [f for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,f))]

parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)


for d in docs:
    x = []
    tree = etree.parse(d,parser)

    for node in [z for z in  tree.iterfind(".//LM")]:
        x.append([node.text,
                  node.get('lemma'),
                  look_up(node.get('catg'))])
        if node.tail.rstrip():
            x.append([node.tail.rstrip(),
                      node.tail.rstrip(),
                      look_up(node.tail.rstrip())])

    df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```